# How do I solve this error message- I'm trying to draw a scatter plot with a line of best fit

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

Please I'm trying to use jupyter notebook to draw a scatter plot and insert a line of best fit in it. When I write the code without this line:
plt.plot (X, regression.predict(X), color='red')
It draws the scatter plot, but when I insert the line above to draw a line of best fit, the error below is outputed.

```
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
data = pandas.read_csv("cost_revenue_clean.csv")
data.describe()
X = DataFrame (data, columns = ['production_budget_usd'])
y = DataFrame (data, columns = ['worldwide_gross_usd'])
regression = LinearRegression()
regression.fit(X, y)
regression.coef_
regression.intercept_
plt.figure(figsize = (10,6))
plt.scatter(X,y, alpha=0.3)
plt.plot (X, regression.predict(X), color='red')
plt.title ('revenue vs budget')
plt.xlabel('prod. budget $')
plt.ylabel('worldwide revenue $')
plt.xlim(0,450000000)
plt.ylim(0,3000000000)
plt.show()
```

I get the error pasted below. I have no idea what the problem could be. I have tried
restarting the kernel several times. I'm pretty new to python and jupyter notebook

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in 
Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:136, in 
pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
 
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:142, in 
pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), None)' is an invalid key

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [9], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 plt.figure(figsize = (10,6))
      2 plt.scatter(X,y, alpha=0.3)
----> 3 plt.plot (X, regression.predict(X), color='red')
      4 plt.title ('revenue vs budget')
      5 plt.xlabel('prod. budget $')

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2757, in plot(scalex, scaley, 
data, *args, **kwargs)
   2755 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)
   2756 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2757     return gca().plot(
   2758         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley,
   2759         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:1632, in Axes.plot(self, 
scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1390 """
   1391 Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
   1392 
   (...)
   1629 (``'green'``) or hex strings (``'#008000'``).
   1630 """
   1631 kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1632 lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1633 for line in lines:
   1634     self.add_line(line)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:312, in 
_process_plot_var_args.__call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    310     this += args[0],
    311     args = args[1:]
--> 312 yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:487, in 
_process_plot_var_args._plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs)
    484         kw[prop_name] = val
    486 if len(xy) == 2:
--> 487     x = _check_1d(xy[0])
    488     y = _check_1d(xy[1])
    489 else:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py:1327, in _check_1d(x)
   1321 with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
   1322     warnings.filterwarnings(
   1323         "always",
   1324         category=Warning,
   1325         message='Support for multi-dimensional indexing')
-> 1327     ndim = x[:, None].ndim
   1328     # we have definitely hit a pandas index or series object
   1329     # cast to a numpy array.
   1330     if len(w) > 0:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3505, in 
DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506 if is_integer(indexer):
   3507     indexer = [indexer]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3628, in 
Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3623         raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624     except TypeError:
   3625         # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626         #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627         #  the TypeError.
-> 3628         self._check_indexing_error(key)
   3629         raise
   3631 # GH#42269

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5637, in 
Index._check_indexing_error(self, key)
   5633 def _check_indexing_error(self, key):
   5634     if not is_scalar(key):
   5635         # if key is not a scalar, directly raise an error (the code below
   5636         # would convert to numpy arrays and raise later any way) - GH29926
-> 5637         raise InvalidIndexError(key)

InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, None), None)
```

Comment: Think about your .plot() call and what you want to do. Examine the X and Y values you input into `plt.plot` before you try to plot them. Are they both 1d numpy arrays? You want to draw a straight line - I would not use the X values from your data, but just equidistant X values, for example np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 10) where xmin, xmax are the limits of the range.

Comment: Also, as a tip, do already get a habit of using the object oriented matplotlib interface. Create axes with `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and use `ax` for all the plotting methods. (`ax.scatter..` ; `ax.plot(..`, `ax.set_title(..` etc).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. And the thing is, that this code works in PyCharm but not in Anaconda. So I thought something is wrong with Anaconda. But then I saw this code and it worked in Anaconda.

```
# create object

regression = LinearRegression()



# perform linear regression

regression.fit(x.values, y.values)



fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

ax.scatter(x, y, s=40, alpha=0.3)



ax.plot(x.values, regression.predict(x.values), color="red", linewidth=4)



plt.title("Film Cost vs Global Revenue")

plt.xlabel("Production Budget $")

plt.ylabel("Worldwide Gross $")



plt.xlim(0, 450000000)

plt.ylim(0, 3000000000)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).